# Mysql view from tables without duplicates and a concatenated column

Tags: mysql, concatenation, union

I need to collect data from different tables, without duplicates and with a column that collects the presence where I've found each item. So, this is my scenario:

TABLEA

| itemId | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Sam |

TABLEB

| itemId | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 3 | Thomas |

I need a view with this result:

| itemId | source_tables |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TABLEA,TABLEB |
| 2 | TABLEA |
| 3 | TABLEB |

## TRY 1 with this simple UNION query

SELECT TABLEA.itemId AS itemId, 'TABLEA' AS source_tables FROM TABLEA

UNION

SELECT TABLEB.itemId AS itemId, 'TABLEB' AS source_tables FROM TABLEB

I get this result:

itemId  source_tables
1   TABLEA
2   TABLEA
1   TABLEB
3   TABLEB

but itemId obviously are duplicated.

## TRY 2 with this query

SELECT itemId, group_concat(source_table separator ';') AS source_tables FROM
(
SELECT itemId, 'TABLEA' AS source_table FROM TABLEA

UNION ALL

SELECT itemId, 'TABLEB' AS source_table FROM TABLEB
) T1
GROUP BY itemId

I get the expected result. Does anybody knows a better way? is it the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.itemid, case when b.name is null then 'tablea' else 'tablea,tableb' end as source_tables
from tablea a
left join tableb b
using(itemid,name)
union
select b.itemid, case when a.name is null then 'tableb' else 'tablea,tableb' end as source_tables
from tablea a
right join tableb b
using(itemid,name)
;

-- result set:
# itemid    source_tables
1   tablea,tableb
2   tablea
3   tableb
```

Note: Since the ORDER BY clause does not work in UNION, if sorting is required, make the UNION statement a subquery(derived table) so we can use the ORDER BY clause on it then.

```
select * 
from (
    select a.itemid, case when b.name is null then 'tablea' else 'tablea,tableb' end as source_tables
    from tablea a
    left join tableb b
    using(itemid,name)
    union
    select b.itemid, case when a.name is null then 'tableb' else 'tablea,tableb' end as source_tables
    from tablea a
    right join tableb b
    using(itemid,name)
    ) t
order by itemid desc -- here we sort in descending order
;

--result set:
# itemid    source_tables
3   tableb
2   tablea
1   tablea,tableb
```